# VBA to add multiple hyperlinks to one Powerpoint text box

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm using a VBA loop in Powerpoint to import data from Excel and write each new string that has been imported as a new bullet in the text box on the slide. This works fine. Then a hyperlink that is also imported should be added to each bullet. This works except that only the last bullet keeps its hyperlink. I suspect that the hyperlink is added not specifically to the bullet but to the text box and therefore is overwritten with each new bullet leaving only the bottom bullet with a hyperlink. Any idea how I can get all bullets' hyperlinks to remain?

Many thanks!

[image]

```
new_slide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.text = new_slide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.text & vbNewLine & new_text

With new_slide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Find(new_text).ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
    .Action = ppActionHyperlink
    .Hyperlink.Address = excel_link
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{modified version}

It works if we add the text first, then step through each line, adding the hyperlink a line at a time. You'll need to either step through your XL import twice, once for the text, once for the hyperlinks:

```
Sub RoundTwo()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim x As Long
    
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    
    For x = 1 To 3
        With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = .Text & vbNewLine & "Some new text"
        End With
    Next
    
    For x = 1 To 3
        Call AddLinkToLine(oSh, x)
    Next
    
End Sub

Sub AddLinkToLine(oSh As Shape, lLine As Long)
    With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lLine)
        With .ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
            .Action = ppActionHyperlink
            .Hyperlink.Address = "http://www.pptfaq.com"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - however same issue remains - only the last line keeps the hyperlink, added image to question

Comment: @Fred Are you adding new lines of text one by one and calling the AddLinkToLastLine function each time you add a new line?  You'd need to do that.

Comment: yes, and if I use the code provided 'as is' alone and execute 3 times I get the result shown in my question. I.e. 3 lines of text but only the last line keeps its hyperlink.

Comment: @Fred I believe you may've lifted the rock that a bug lives under.  See the edited version of my answer.

Comment: Great - for some reason I needed to add 2 paragraph lines "Paragraphs(lLine + 2)" but then your new version worked perfect - many thanks!

Comment: @Fred That'd be the case if you're adding lines to an existing text box and only want the hyperlink applied to newly added lines.  Glad it helped.